# install centos from USB

Tags: centos

I create USB with kickstart and it work

On the isolinux.cfg I add:

LABEL Appliance Installation
    IPAPPEND 2
    KERNEL vmlinuz
    APPEND initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=Appliance7 ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg

But when I try to install it on Intel server type 5500 product S1200RP it hang on

"random: crng init done"

I change the isolinux.cfg ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg to ks=file:/ks.cfg

It is not hang but i get that says anconda missing ks.cfg

when I check the anaconda log is looking for the kickstart on directory /run/install but all the the kickstart is on mounted directory /run/install/repo

So i copy the kickstart to directory /run/install during the installation and it work

How I can fix it that will take the kickstart from /run/install/repo or any else action to make it run

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this page: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/chap-anaconda-boot-options `inst.ks` (and hopefully its deprecated `ks` equivalent as well) allows to specify device for the ks file (look at `inst.repo` details). So you hopefully can use `inst.ks=hd:device:/path` format and specify `device`  by device name, LABEL= or UUID= and then use this partition's relative path